# wpf datagrid generated comboboxcolums show results in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a code generated Datatable that is added via code to DataGrid:

```
// out GMBD); <<-- get results from api

DataTable table = new DataTable();

if (y != 0)
{
    string err = apicall.GetErrorText(y);
    MessageBox.Show(err);
}
else
{
    // Get max/ Add columns and columns name
    for (int column = 0; column < GMBD.ColumnCount; column++)
    {
            table.Columns.Add(GMBD.ColumnName[column],GMBD[0,column].ValueAsObject.GetType());
    }
    // Add rows.
    for (int row = 0; row < GMBD.RowCount; row++)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(GMBD.GetRowAsList(row).Select(x => x.ValueAsObject).ToArray());

    }
    tabla.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
    apicall.Dispose();

}

private void setnew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{

    //if ((string)e.Column.Header== "STATE")
    //{
    //    DataGridComboBoxColumn cboclm = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    //    cboclm.Header = "zzzz"; ///"STATE";
    //    cboclm.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(STATEvariables));
    //    //cboclm.SetValue(cboclm,e.Column.));
    //   // cboclm.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("STATE");
    //    e.Column = cboclm;
    //}
}
```

The column type is predefined in another class.
The DataGrid In XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tabla" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,46,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="543" Width="1162" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="false" EnableColumnVirtualization="false" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=id}" 
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

Tried AutoGeneratingColumn, but it's not good because its called before getting the results.The results columns are unknown,as I don't want show all 20+ columns, only the requested ones by input. 
The problem is that the ComboboxColumn comboboxes don't show any result values, but still contain the predefined values.

Is there a method to show result values in generated comboboxcolumn?

Comment: I think you need to write simple codes to add columns to DataGrid like you add columns to DataTable which are requested specifically by users. And if you get the values needed for DataGridComboBoxColumn in advance of DataGrid creation, save the values to global variables so that the values exist before calling DataGrid. It's just quick and general suggestion but hope this helps..

Comment: The creation of the columns is in another class, that sorts the result values as needed by input and defines the type of the column depending on the the result type. The DataGrid is generated before the values are passed to it. If the `GMBD[0,column].ValueAsObject.GetType()` is removed, it will get the the values right, but no cell type only plain text. The problem is that the combobox gets the variables, but its not showing the result.. Maybe its some kind of binding method that I missed ..